# Merge PDF with FDF output only PDF

Tags: java, pdf, merge, itext

I have a PDF and FDF file and want to merge them into a single PDF. The .pdf has no fields, these are all included in the .fdf file, the contents of the fields also.

I have several solutions found, but these only works when the fields are stored in the pdf.

I would like to use iText with Java.

Does anyone have some demo code how I can solve my problem? Thank you!

Here's some code which only works when the fields are already present in the PDF

```
PdfReader pdfreader = new PdfReader(pdfInPath);   
PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(pdfreader, new FileOutputStream(pdfOutPath));   
FdfReader fdfreader = new FdfReader(fdfInPath);   
AcroFields form = stamp.getAcroFields();   
form.setFields(fdfreader);   
stamp.close();
```

Comment: When you say *The .pdf has no fields*, then you shouldn't expect FDF to work. You need a PDF that contains AcroForm fields. These fields can be empty (in which case merging with the FDF will fill out these fields), but the "placeholders" (aka the fields) need to be there. See my answer to the question [How to save an .xfdf file as a .pdf file?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-save-xfdf-file-pdf-file) in the official FAQ.

Comment: Maybe I did not say it correctly. There are not directly fields, but freehand drawn content, comments or free placeable text boxes. These are stored in the .fdf. And all this I want to store them in one single pdf.

Comment: So you are talking about annotations, not about fields? I know that this wasn't supported in the past. I know that we've put that on the road map at some point in time, but checking the code, I see we never implemented this part. We'll put it on the road map for iText 7.